# How to use f11 on a Mac

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm playing a game called fishing planet and I need to use f11 to change the pitch but it's the volume so I can't use it

Comment: Did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 32):

System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Controls => Locate "F11" and uncheck it for Show Desktop (or whatever it's set as)

Comment: This answer is actually correct if you enable F keys, then for some users, F11 or F12 are actually linked to some system shortcuts. So you actually need this extra step to disable those

Comment: Absolutely, by default at least on my macbook the Fn + F11 key is set to show desktop. So thankful to have found this thread, as I was wondering why the Fn wasn't taking! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this; I was tearing my hair out trying to debug things - F10 would work. F11 would hide everything :)

Answer (score 6):

On macOS 11 Big Sur you can find the option under:

**System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control**

Then disable the F11 shortcut.

Comment: only answer relevant now. system preferences -> search "f11" does not find it of course

Answer (score 5):

Hit the Fn key at the bottom left along with F11. Alternatively, in System Preferences, you can set the F keys to be used as F keys and not as volume etc., so then you won't need to press the Fn key every time.

Answer (score 1):

I find this definition to be helpful towards the question:

> The F11 function key will quickly slide up all your windows, revealing
>   your desktop, and letting you interact with your files and folders. By
>   default on MacBook / Pro / Air, and on the small keyboard for iMac,
>   the F11 key is mapped to special functionality, like decreasing the
>   volume. All you need to do is hold down the "fn" function key (bottom
>   left corner of your keyboard) while pressing the F11 key to trigger
>   the show-desktop command.
>
> source: http://in5stepstutorials.com/mac-os-x/quickly-show-desktop-in-mac-os-x-gesture-hotkey.php

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent. While your post in helpful to understand what the F11 key does usually, it doesn’t really help to solve the problem described in the question. What should the asker do to remove any special meaning from F11 so it works with the application they are using?

Answer (score 0):

The function keys on a mac have certain functions like volume, Expose, etc. Instead, you need the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to press. so <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. On a windows on the other hand, you would use the function key for the F keys functions.

You can do such thing on a mac too in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > Use F1, F2, etc. as standard function keys.

Doing the above will make F11 keys function like on windows. If you need to adjust volume, etc. with this option checked, you use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key for that.